# RegistrationId with GCM after upgrade of app in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In Android App, I get registrationId for sending push notification with GCM by the following code.

```
registrationId = gcm.register("xxxxx");
```

According to several websites, when the app is upgraded, registrationId is changed.

It may be so, however after upgrade, I can send push notification by registrationId of the previous version.

So I think there is no need to reacquire registrationId after upgrade.

Why should I reacquire RegistrationId despite to send push notification by previous registrationId?

Answer (score 0):

Note: It seems like you are not using the recommended way of retrieving identifiers, InstanceID tokens. Have a look at [this sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm) for example of the recommended usage.

More to your question, from the documentation:

> Instance ID is stable but may become invalid, if:
>
> - App deletes Instance ID
> - Device is factory reset
> - User uninstalls the app
> - User clears app data

Given the above application updates should not cause invalidation of tokens.